# Export of all tags, not only your own

Tags: tags, box-api

When you get a list of files through the Box API, you also get the tags assigned to those files in string format. These tags include your own Box tags as well as shared tags (My Tags vs All Tags).

However, if you want to verify in a later phase if some of these tags have been deleted for instance, that seems not possible. The 'export tags' API method only returns your own tags.
This makes it really difficult to keep tags in sync, and I don't see a good reason why you would be able to see tags in the Box UI but not in the API. In the end it's just another representation of the same data, or that's what you would expect.

Anyone knows a possible workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a known workaround for this at this time, but we're in the process of building out tags support in our V2 API and will take this use case into consideration.

Comment: Thanks. Any indication on when tags are to be expected in the v2? We have now dropped Box support all together because of this. No tags in v2, and API v1 has other issues.